# SharePoint ClientContext.ExecuteQuery works in c# application but crashes in DLL

Tags: c#, delphi, sharepoint, dll

I have written C# code to search for specific file types in SharePoint lists within a site and display the file names in a listview.
The code works perfectly well in a C# windows application, but when it is compiled into a C# DLL and called from a Delphi2007 application it crashes when it hits the first call to ClientContext.ExecuteQuery(). There is no exception or error message - the Delphi application just stops running.

The really weird part is that my Delphi test application has a web browser component, and if I use that to navigate to the top level list on the site the DLL then works OK.

The question therefore is why does the first ExecuteQuery call fail in the DLL if I haven't logged on to the site first?

This is the C# code:

```
        public void ListFiles()
        {
            string LContains = "<Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>   <Value Type ='Text'>{0}</Value></Contains>";
            string LNotEqual = "<Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type ='Text'>{0}</Value></Contains>";
            string LWhereQuery = "";

            switch (comboFileType.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: LWhereQuery = string.Format(LContains, ".DOC"); break;
                case 1: LWhereQuery = string.Format(LContains, ".PDF"); break;
                case 2: LWhereQuery = string.Format(LNotEqual, "xxxx"); break;
            }


            Uri LUri = new Uri(SharePointURL);
            using (SP.ClientContext LContext = new SP.ClientContext(SharePointURL))
            {
                System.Net.CredentialCache cc = new System.Net.CredentialCache();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain))
                    cc.Add(LUri, AuthenticationType, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain));
                else
                    cc.Add(LUri, AuthenticationType, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password));

                LContext.Credentials = cc;
                LContext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

                var LWeb = LContext.Web;
                lvItems.BeginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SP.List LList = LWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(DefaultListName);

                        SP.CamlQuery LQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                        LQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where>"
                            + LWhereQuery
                            + "</Where></Query><RowLimit> 30 </RowLimit></View>";

                        SP.ListItemCollection LItems = LList.GetItems(LQuery);

                        LContext.Load(LItems);
                        LContext.ExecuteQuery();  **<<<< Crash happens here**

                            foreach (SP.ListItem LItem in LItems)
                            {
                                SP.File LFile = LItem.File;
                                LContext.Load(LFile);
                                LContext.ExecuteQuery();

                                var LViewItem = new ListViewItem();

                                try { LViewItem.Text = LFile.Name; }
                                catch { LViewItem.Text = "!Error"; }

                                try { LViewItem.SubItems.Add(LFile.TimeLastModified.ToString()); }
                                catch { LViewItem.SubItems.Add("!Error"); }

                                if (LFile.CheckOutType != Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckOutType.None)
                                {
                                    try { LViewItem.SubItems.Add(LFile.CheckedOutByUser.LoginName); }
                                    catch { LViewItem.SubItems.Add("!Error"); }
                                }
                                else
                                    LViewItem.SubItems.Add("Not checked out.");

                                try { LViewItem.Tag = LFile.ServerRelativeUrl; }
                                catch { LViewItem.Tag = "!Error"; }

                                lvItems.Items.Add(LViewItem);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    lvItems.EndUpdate();
                }

        }
```

The code is in the .cs of a dialog form in the DLL. The form displays as it should and the crash only happens when I click a button to do the search.

I put some debug code in to check all the string params etc. (by writing them to a text file) and they are all OK.

I tried debugging the DLL from VS by specifying the D2007 app as the 'startup external program' but I can't get breakpoints to work and at the point where it crashes it says: *An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll* and suggests I might have an infinite recursive call but, as mentioned earlier, the code all works perfectly if I have already logged into the site and browsed to the top level list, so i don't think it is a recursive call.

UPDATE: I got the debugging to work by copying the Delphi exe to the same directory as the DLL.

I've tried using the ExceptionHandlingScope but it hasn't helped. This is how it looks when it crashes:

[image: StackOverflow error in MSSP client runtime dll]

The scope has no exception and the errormessage is blank. I tried a few connotations of what was inside the scope but to no avail.

The whole code block is in a try..catch and I've tried wrapping the ExecuteQuery line in it's own try..catch as well, but nothing catches it. The app crashes out every time when I hit continue.

I've also tried putting an execute query before loading the web but it still crashes out.

I'm thinking this has to be something to do with credentials? If I deliberately put the wrong username I get a polite '401 Unauthorized' back and no crash. And if I'm already logged in it doesn't crash either?

Comment: I suspect your problem may be exception handling. Is there any chance that you are effectively trying to pass an exception across the DLL/Delphi boundary? This is absolutely forbidden, and your stack overflow could be the result of an exception generating an exception generating an exception... You may need to wrap all your interface calls (in the dll) with exception traps that return a non zero value. I know how to do that in Delphi, but not c#, sadly.

Comment: @Dsm: Thanks for the reply. Most of the methods are within Try..Catch blocks which are the C# equivalent of Try..Except in Delphi. I handle all exceptions in the code (I think!) and pass a string error message across the com boundary when required. As the stack overflow error mentions the MSP client runtime library it suggests the problem is between the C# code and that library? It may be that I haven't trapped something on the form so I'll take another look there.

Comment: probably safest to do a catch-all at the very highest level, as well as trying to catch each individual one. So, if ListFiles is exported, it should have a try - catch around the entire code, even the initial string assignments, even though they should never generate an exception. It is just a safety first thing.

Comment: I've added more Try..Catch blocks and removed all MessageBox.Show() instances in case they were part of the problem, b ut none of that has helped. I also found this [article about using Scope](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2015/07/30/managing-clientcontext-executequery-errors-in-sharepoint-csom/) and put a Scope wrapper around the first executequery, but the crash still happens with the same results.

Comment: Shame. Maybe MSP client isn't so well behaved.

Comment: Have you tried calling the DLL from a c# application? Does the same thing occur?

Comment: @Dsm: Good point! I just tried that and the DLL works OK from a C# application, which implies that it is probably a wider issue with the Delphi implementation rather than a specific issue with the ClientContext?

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that. C# must implicitly do something that Delphi does not.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the C# test application I tried the same with Delphi XE8 and that also worked, so in the end I've resorted to writing an intermediate DLL in XE8.

I noticed that when importing the TLB from the C# DLL into XE8 it behaved differently from D2007 in that it complained about other missing TLB's when building - notably the system.windows.forms library (and some dependencies). I'm not sure if this has any bearing on XE8 working and D2007 failing, but hopefully it well help anyone else needing a workaround.